# Coverting a numeric variable into a ordinal variable

Tags: r

I am working on a data set that contains a variable called "JobSatisfaction" that is shown as int [1,2,3,4].  In order to proceed with my data analysis, I need to convert this variable into a ordinal variable.

JobSatisfaction is supposed to have four levels: 
low, medium, high, very high

After that I will need to do a linear regression.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: `data.frame(JobSatisfaction=factor(c(2,1,3,4,2,1), levels=1:4, labels=c("low", "medium", "high", "very high")))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use `ordered()`. Here is an example

```
df <- data.frame(code = rep(letters[1:4], 5),
                 JobSatisfaction =  sample(rep(1:4,5))) # data frame df
df$JobSatisfaction <- ordered(df$JobSatisfaction, levels = 1:4,
                              labels = c("low", "medium", "high", "veryhigh")) # conversion
```

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for a solution that convert a integer numeric variable into an ordered categorical variable.

I suggest you to use the package `dplyr` because for this task it is perfect.

```
    dplyr::mutate(my_df,  
                      JobSatisfaction = 
                          dplyr::recode_factor(JobSatisfaction,   
                             `1`="low", `2`="medium",  
                             `3`="high", `4` = "very high",  
                             .ordered = TRUE)
```

`recode` is used for mapping the value of a variable to new values

the parameter `.ordered = TRUE` allows us to define that `low < medium < high < very_high`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `factor()` for this:

```
JobSatisfaction =  sample(rep(1:4,10)) #Create dataset
JobSatisfaction = factor(JobSatisfaction,levels=1:4,labels = c("low","medium","high","veryhigh"),ordered=T)
```

Note: corrected the second line after @ANG comment.

Comment: `...levels = 1:4...` instead of `...levels = :4...`